# How to prevent tomcat7 repeat context name in apache proxy setup

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I have this problem where my apache forward http request to tomcat using proxy (see my apache virtual host config below).It works fine, but the web http request http://subdomain.example.com/xyz/images/background2.jpg arrive at tomcat as /xyz/xyz/images/background2.jpg. context name "xyz" appear twice which cause missing resource at tomcat end.

How do you resolve this problem ?

Apache Virtual Host config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8080/xyz/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8080/xyz/
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat project setup:  ../tomcat7/webapps/xyz/...

Answer (score 1):

You need to update ProxyPass settings as below.

```
ProxyPass /xyz/ http://www.example.com:8080/xyz/
ProxyPassReverse /xyz/ http://www.example.com:8080/xyz/
```

Comment: My project is placed in Tomcat as ../tomcat7/webapps/xyz/.... My intention is to map subdomain.example.com url to tomcat project url http://www.example.com:8080/xyz/, hence the setup above. I don't want to rename my project as ROOT also as I learnt it is not recommend by tomcat.